# Creating multiple identical elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to `create` a new `item` which will essentially have the same structure of all of the other `items` in the same `list`. I have looked into `append` but I'm wondering if there is an easier way than writing out my structure using `append`.

In a perfect world I could duplicate the last `li` in a `ul` on `click` of a create button and have a new element added to the DOM that is an exact copy of the last `ul` child (less any of the information that might be in the last item).

**OR** maybe I could have a dummy element already created and each time the user clicks the create button a new instance of this dummy is added?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) with your dummy (ie _template_) element idea

Answer (score 2):

It may easy to do, please check my code snipet bellow:

```js
var listEl = $('.list');
$('.create-btn').on('click', function() {
  var lastItemNode = listEl.find('li:last-child').clone();
  listEl.append(lastItemNode);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

<button class="create-btn">Create new item</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the HTML5 `template` element?

> The HTML Content Template () element is a mechanism for holding client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is loaded but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using JavaScript.

-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

You can get the content and use jQuery to create a new element from it.

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#list').append($('#new-li').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="new-li">
  <li>
    Hello World!
  </li>
</template>

<ul id="list">

</ul>

<button type="button" id="add">+ NEW</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.clone` on the last element:

```js
$('div').on('click', () => {
  $('ul').append($('ul > li:last-child').clone())
});
```

```css
.li-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>click</div>
<ul>
<li class="li-class">li text here</li>
</ul>
```